# Tree shaking CSS using angular-cli build / schematics

Tags: javascript, css, angular, components, angular-cli

I am on an angular-cli project. I am facing an issue with the CSS. This is somewhat a non-code question and deviates from Stack Overflow needs of putting code. But hopefully it will not be marked down for closure. Here is the background:

I have a lot of unnecessary CSS lingering around. I need tree shaking for the unnecessary CSS during the build process. Is there one that you can help me with.

Here is the background of what is happening:

- I was trying to move to scss and saw there are a lot of extra classes created than what I would have when using manually.
- So I moved to plain manually created snippets of CSS manually written and some pulled out from a framework (bootstrap). Since these are snippets not all are used in the development. But since the framework has a lot of extra CSS that covers the entirety of a cause (say responsive grid), it leaves back a lot of css that are not used.
- So to reduce the overhead, I tried to move to a native shadow-dom based component. But I saw my CSS being repeated for a lot of components.
- I have now put all the CSS back to the main `styles.css` (`style1.css`, `style1.css` etc concatenated by ng-cli) to help clean the CSS faster and moved to default angular emulation for components. But as my application is growing bigger I am not able to track the CSS manually.

Options:
I see manual tree shaking is an issue. So I saw there are a few CSS treeshakers around but since Angular cli works with multiple components, I see a need of cli integration of the CSS tree shaker. I could not find one for cli to merge with build.

Questions: Anyone has suggestion on how to integrate or is there a CSS-tree shaker community project? I have not worked with schematics.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by treeshaking unnecessary CSS? Could you provide a generic example?

Comment: Like treesharking unused variables and imports using cli

Comment: Here is someones actual ground work. https://github.com/simlrh/dead-css-loader let me check what is in store until you reply.

Comment: Practically, it's neither possible nor practical. You'd need to compile every single variant of the page and it would fail anyway considering CSS preprocessors and `ng-class` directive. A good CSS shaker would need to understand and apply specificity. Besides, the gain would not be worth the effort. The only hiccup of CSS is loading, not processing. Also, have you conducted any comparison tests of actual improvement? Just repeat same rule 1k times and see if there's any significant difference in load and parse.

Comment: Yes, this is what I too was thinking. I was looking at a css cleaner blog. I deciphered you can match css classes in html and ngClass and ngStyle. However, I realised a pure js with css code out of detection will mess it up as well. What options are available if I use a constraint of css classes only in html, ngclass, ngstyle? Would I be able to identify them using the new renderer? Let's ignore the fact that we will ever use a preprocessor.